# Counting of colored cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on access based WinForm application. I have colored cell(DateColumn) in my DataGridView. I am trying to count colored cells as shown in pic and want to reflect total No. of colored cell on a label's text. I tried below codes which are not counting my DataGridView's total No. of colored cells although counting total rows. Exact problem can be understand with the help of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G20eK.png) image

My Codes are as follows:

```
private void metroGrid1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.metroGrid1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Date 1")
            try
            {
                var EMIDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(metroGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["date1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);

                for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid1.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (EMIDate1 <= DateTime.Today)
                    {
                        int countDarkRed = 0;
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.metroGrid1.Rows)
                        {

                            if (row.Cells["date1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Style.BackColor == Color.DarkRed)
                            {
                                countDarkRed++;
                            }
                        }
                        labelEMI.Text = "Total EMI due as on today:" + countDarkRed;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? you expect to have `countDarkRed = 1` but it's `0`?

Comment: I could not understand what you want. Do you want to count how many cells have Dark Red background? Why not add a counter when you set the color?

Comment: @NoChance  I want to count all the Dark Red Cells and also need to show this number on label.text & Unable to understand the meaning of this line "Why not add a counter when you set the color?".

Comment: @GiulioCaccin My problem is that I am unable to count all Dark Red Color and can you tell Why I should have countDarkRed = 1 although DataGridView does not have any Dark Red Cell in begining.

Comment: The easiest way is to increment a counter when you change the cell color, not to count colored cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer*
You want to set the styles in the grid's cell, not only in the current formatting session of the cell. You are colouring the wrong CellStyle. Directly access the grid cell style instead of using the event cell and your code will do what you want (tested on my machine):

```
        if (EMIDate1 <= DateTime.Today)
        {
            this.metroGrid1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
            this.metroGrid1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
```

*Long Answer*
**DONT DO THIS**

- The formatting event will be applied only on VISIBLE cells
  rows or columns hidden because the control/windows is too small will not trigger this code
- You are mixing formatting logic (colours) with business logic (expired dates)
  try to do this check before even binding the grid, or make another call to the database
- The documentation explicitly discurage to do too much process inside the cell formatting event 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks
- This code will be executed every time there is a windows redraw, mouse over, etc, making your label one of the most expensive labels in your program
  you should make that counting just once

*Complete working example*
Create a window form application with just one datagridview and a label

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = new[] { 
            new {Title = "bella", Date1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)}, 
            new {Title = "ciao", Date1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(12)}, 
            new {Title = "bella", Date1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)}, 
            new {Title = "ciao", Date1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31)}, 
            new {Title = "bella", Date1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(11)}, 
            new { Title= "ciao", Date1 = DateTime.Today} ,
            new { Title= "ciao", Date1 = DateTime.Today} ,
            new { Title= "ciao", Date1 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)} };

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Date1")
        {
            var date = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Date1"].Value as DateTime?;
            if (date.HasValue && date.Value <= DateTime.Today)
            {
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;

            }

            int countDarkRed = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["Date1"].Style.BackColor == Color.DarkRed)
                    countDarkRed++;
            }
            label1.Text = $"dark = {countDarkRed}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir, @Giulio sorry for late reply. Your codes are awesome working perfectly. Thanks. Can you help me about what should i edit in my above question? So that I will be able to ask more questions. As of now I am blocked from asking anymore question.

Answer (score 0):

Where you went wrong in the previous case was, you were checking only the first cell and kept incrementing the count, now you've confused my comments on your previous question. Here's the outline:

There is one if loop to check the date and change color, and one for loop to count the number of cells that have changed color

```
private void metroGrid1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.metroGrid1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Date 1")
    {
        try
        {
            int countDarkRed = 0;
            var EMIDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(metroGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["date1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);

            //Checking whether we have to turn it red or not
            if (EMIDate1 <= DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }

            //Checking how many cells have turned red
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in this.metroGrid1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["date1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Style.BackColor == Color.DarkRed)
                {
                    countDarkRed++;
                }
            }
            labelEMI.Text = "Total EMI due as on today:" + countDarkRed;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did little change in your code foreach(DataGridViewRow row in this.metroGrid1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells["date1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Style.BackColor == Color.DarkRed)
                        {
                            countDarkRed++;
                        }
              labelEMI.Text = "Total EMI due as on today:" + countDarkRed;   }
 This is showing serial no. of last colored cell. Your actual code does not showing counting on label's text.  Please help

Comment: try debugging to see where it went wrong, I can't see anything wrong with this code, perhaps, there might be something overwriting this data, I can't say for sure until I can see the complete program

Comment: this code is not working, you should reference the grid, not the current formatting session cell, when setting the style